# Where do you post questions that are not "permitted" in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm still somewhat new although getting the hang of Stack Overflow.

I have asked a couple of questions now that were closed or put on hold as being either too broad or asking for opinions on best practices.  Given the downvotes and other frowns that appear with these questions, I quickly deleted them to not offend anyone.

I've learned Stack Overflow is mostly for very specific short questions with direct answers, but where is the proper place to post questions that are more broad or opinion based like asking for best practices (for example with javascript, node.js, php, mongodb, etc.) or if a certain technique is better than another technique?

Comment: There is no place on the SE network for these types of questions, AFAIK. However, depending on the type of question, you may be able to ask on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/72674/) though you will want to read their FAQ and about asking questions before posting. Also know that deleting posts isn't always the best idea. When they are put on hold, you can edit them and possibly get them reopened if you can make them fit the SO criteria.

Comment: ONESTLY, go out into meatspace. yes, the world of touch. The *real* world. Ask people, walk up and say "hi" then launch into all the opninion based-questions you have. Always smile.

Comment: @Coffee I find *"randomly"* starting a conversation in *meatspace* about programming inverses my gravitational field. :/

Comment: Some of the tags have very active chat rooms (like PHP), so you can ask there, or as suggested, forums. There are blogs aplenty on most programming topics. My learning cycle involves either starting with Google, or a recommendation from chat, then reading, researching trying, and **then**, if I struggle with a specific thing, is it time to ask a question. After you check Google, and search SO, and maybe even ask in chat.

Comment: One persistent off-topic category of questions, software recommendations, [actually has its own site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (in beta) that few people on SO actually know about.

Comment: +1 for managing to get this question closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Broad and opinion-based questions should be asked at a **Forum**. Another possibility would be the various chat rooms.

Don't forget that there are also other StackExchange sites for different perspectives on programming, such as:

- **[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**:

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle.

- **[CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**:

> Code Review is a question and answer site for sharing code from projects you are working on
> for peer review.

- **[CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**:

> Code Golf is a question and answer site for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers.

For all sites, see [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).