# Would these suggestions help manage question quality?

Tags: discussion, voting, questions, asking-questions

**Require code block** - Some of the terrible questions I've noticed could be addressed by requiring that there is at least one `code` block in the initial question. If the assumption is that you should have at least done some work before posting your question, then there would be only one or two reasons I could think of to not post code: security. intellectual property. None of the questions I've seen without code fall into that category.

-

**Redirecting questions** - Another is somehow making alternative resources for questions related to conceptual application, code review, and coding games more visible. The information provided in the answer below would be rather helpful in that regard.

[Where do you post questions that are not "permitted" in StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253185/where-do-you-post-questions-that-are-not-permitted-in-stackoverflow)

There could be a system where higher rep users have the option to vote "conceptual", "review", or "game". X number of votes would transfer the question to the appropriate StackExchange site, maybe even with an option to require X votes from the community to accept it: "accept" "accept as duplicate" "reject". Accept as duplicate could link the question to other similar questions and the user could have a chance to revise to make the question original, or just use the relevant information. With appropriate tags question grouping could even be automatic.

-

**HomeworkOverflow** - Finally, why not make a HomeworkOverflow? We could direct all blatant, no effort, or conceptual homework questions there, and people who are interested, or people also doing homework, could support those users. If no one supports, they would be left to research on their own.

Comment: Requiring a code block will only lead to people adding codeblocks with nothing of consequence in them. And there are plenty of fine questions that don't require a code block at all.

Comment: We *already* have options to migrate questions, but that's reserved for high-quality questions only.

Comment: Homework Overflow has been proposed before. The problem is that no experts would frequent it, and that homework questions are not the issue here, but the *quality of the question itself*. Just dumping a homework question and a 'dunno how to do this' line is not going to work anywhere.

Comment: Feature request: bulk-upvote comments without wasting 15 seconds.

Comment: Got it. Just a few ideas from a fresh pair of eyes. Back to my regularly scheduled day.

Answer (score 7):

**Require code block**

Not every question requires a block of code. Many do. Many should. But not all. By making it a requirement you'll get stupid stuff like this in every question.

```
fake 
code 
block
```

(See also the contortions people perform to get the word "problem" in their question titles.)

**Redirecting questions**

Isn't this already covered by the existing migration procedure? I think that's well established. The default four (plus Meta) in the Migration dialog were chosen specifically due to their popularity and usefulness. If you think that should change maybe you should add a feature request.

**HomeworkOverflow**

And how will this attract experts to answer the questions? Sure, you get a convenient "crap question ghetto" to send some of these people and their questions to, but who's going to take the time to go there and actually answer the questions? Sure, some people who love shiny badges and meaningless points, but it would mostly just collapse under its own weight. Other sites in Stack Exchange have been shut down because they weren't focused to attract experts on their topic.

So no, I don't think your suggestions will help with question quality.